# Aurora MySQL Serverless V1 to V2 Migration Doesn't Migrate - Rolls Back Version During Process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

This is driving me insane, so hopefully someone can help.

I am attempting to upgrade/migrate an Aurora MySQL Serverless instance from V1 to V2 [utilizing the process found in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.upgrade.html#aurora-serverless-v2.upgrade-from-serverless-v1-procedure). When I reach step 4...

> Restore the snapshot to create a new, provisioned DB cluster running Aurora MySQL version 3 that's compatible with Aurora Serverless v2, for example, 3.02.0.

... the database that results from the restored snapshot is Aurora v2 again, even though the cluster was v3 until the database was created. This means that I can't change it to Serverless V2 (I hate how confusing these version numbers are...).

I've tried several different tiers and types of provisioned databases for the interim copies, and I've tried using the CLI tool in case it was an issue with the GUI, and I get the same result every time.

Has anyone ran into this? Am I just missing something? I'm pretty much at a complete loss here, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what happened initially, but trying again on a different day resulted in an error log. Previously, no logs were coming through on the migrated instance. It may have been my impatience then, but at least now I have an answer.

In my case, it was some corrupted Views that were part of some legacy code that was disallowing the migration. If anyone else runs into this, make sure you give the log files time to generate, and look at the `upgrade_prechecks.log` file to see what the actual errors are.

[More information about the logs and how to find them can be found in the official documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.mysql80-upgrade-procedure.html#AuroraMySQL.mysql80-upgrade-troubleshooting)